# How to make a UIAlert button press advance to next Storyboard?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I'm quite new to Swift (and coding in general) and to this website.

I'm having a little bit of an issue now. In my app, I have an alert when a timer reaches 0. In that alert, there are 2 buttons. One says "Share" and the other says "Continue". I want to make it such that when a user taps "Continue", the next Storyboard will be shown to them. As of now, whatever button I press will dismiss the alert, but stay on the same Storyboard. (It also prints to the console which button I pressed, but of course that's just for me to see).

How do I go about doing this? Here is my code, in case anyone wants to know.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Time's Up!", message: "What would you like to do now?", preferredStyle: .Alert)
let firstAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Continue", style: .Default) { (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
    NSLog("You pressed button one")
}

let secondAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Share", style: .Default) { (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
    NSLog("You pressed button two")
}

alert.addAction(firstAction)
alert.addAction(secondAction)
presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion:nil)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far, in terms of presenting the next storyboard? None of the code you showed seems to interact with storyboards, so it's hard to help with this. See [ask]

Comment: you meant next scene(view controller) in the same storyboard? or next scene(view controller) in next storyboard

Comment: @jtbandes Admittedly I don't know too much about presenting the next Storyboard in my app. Right now, what I am doing is in Main.storyboard, I Control drag a button in one ViewController to another ViewController and when the small black popup appears I click modal and that's it. In the Attributes Inspector I just choose some other animation. That's all I know.

Comment: @Johnykutty I hope I'm not being confusing, but I have one Main.storyboard file and multiple "screens" (ViewControllers) in that one file.

Comment: Only one .storyboard file means you have to present next scene from same storyboard itself. I hope http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1 will help you

Comment: @Johnykutty thanks for the link, I will take a look. Interestingly enough, thats the website I used when I first started coding. Good times... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try with this:**

```
// Create the alert controller
    var alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .Alert)

// Create the actions
    var okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
        UIAlertAction in
        NSLog("OK Pressed")
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("someViewController") as UIViewController
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    var cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) {
        UIAlertAction in
        NSLog("Cancel Pressed")
        //do whatever you want here
    }

// Add the actions
    alertController.addAction(okAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

// Present the controller
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

If you haven't already set your `ViewControllerIdentifier`:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8M7Ia.png]

You need to set the Identifier value that you can find on the right column

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I will definitely try this and see how it goes.

Comment: @ryanbangras no problem! and if you haven't already set the ViewControllerIdentifier check the edit

Comment: Okay so I tried putting this into my code, but I got errors anytime "var" was mentioned. The popup for the errors say "Variable _name_ was never mutated. Consider changing to 'let' constant. And in the line ` presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)` I get an error which says "Implicit use of 'self' in closure; use "self." to make capture semantics explicit. I am a total noob when it comes to coding and I have next to no idea what this means. Please advise. **Edit: I haven't seen your edit, I might try that**

Comment: Hmm... I can't seem to find ViewControllerIdentifier anywhere. The closest thing I can find is View Controller Title which has a checkbox beneath it saying "Is Initial View Controller" and then a section dedicated to Custom Class, Module, Storyboard ID and Restoration ID. I also have no idea what to do with any of these.

Comment: @ryanbangras I've edited some of the code, try it now. You have to set the Storyboard ID of the ViewController you want to start (in my code example the ViewController identifier is "someViewController"). What you need to do on the code is just edit the name of the Storyboard "MyStoryboardName" with your Storyboard name and the ViewController ID "someViewController"  with the Storyboard ID you gave to the ViewController

Comment: I am so sorry if this is dragging on for too long but I don't quite understand what you mean. I mean, I've coped and pasted your code and Xcode still gave me the error asking me to replace var with let and assuming it wasn't that big of a problem I just did it. But there is now a new error that shows up under `let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("someViewController") as! UIViewController` and it says _"Forced cast of 'UIViewController' to same type has no effect."_ The suggested fix is to remove as! UIViewController. Please help, and thanks for tolerating me.

Comment: @ryanbangras sry if I answer just now, I've edited the code and removed the ! after as, btw if you use my same code you must have declared the Storyboard ID of your ViewController as "someViewController" or it won't work, if you set a different Storyboard ID make sure to also change the code with the correct ID

Comment: My gosh, after so long I finally got it! When you said I had to name my Storyboard, I was thinking that I had to give my ViewController a "title" under the Attributes inspector, and that _that_ was the name! Only after rereading what you wrote did I realize that you meant the actual **name** of my Storyboard file, which was just Main.storyboard. Thank you so so much for the help man. I'll mark this answer as correct. Take care! :) @Signo

Comment: @ryanbangras np, glad I could help you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that might help you. When you create a AlertController with actions, you can provide the actions and style of the button when you define them. In code below action is in the closure (Block) and style is defined as `.Default` or `.Cancel`

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Time's Up!", message: "What would you like to do now?", preferredStyle: .Alert)
let firstAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Continue", style: .Default) { (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in

   // Action when you press button goes here 
      print("Here you show next storyboard item.")
  //  Code to push new ViewController. For example : 
      self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newVCInstance, animated: true)
}

let secondAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Share", style: .Default) { (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
 print("Here you share things.")
    // Code to share things.
}

let thirdAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: . Cancel) { (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
     print("Just dismissing the Alert Controller.")
}


alert.addAction(firstAction)
alert.addAction(secondAction)
alert.addAction(thirdAction)
```

presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion:nil)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will also try out your code and let you know how it goes!

Comment: Hey, I tried out your code and just like the other guy I get the same errors. Xcode is telling me to use let instead of var and then **"Implicit use of 'self' in closure; use "self." to make capture semantics explicit."** in the line:  presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
What do I do?

Comment: Xcode is telling to use let instead of var, so replace var with let. Actually here Xcode detects if you create a data member and do not update it later. So Xcode suggesting you to use let, which means it's not going to change in future.

Comment: With regard to "Implicit use of 'self' in closure; ...." replace  presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil) with self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: The errors are gone, but one new one pops up - it says Use of unresolved identifier 'vc'. What do I do about this? @Anupam

Comment: This vc is instance of ViewController you want to present. So replace it with your Viewcontroller you want to present.

Comment: If the solutions works for you, you can hit accept button for suitable answer to you.

Comment: Thanks for the help man, I eventually used the other guy's answer and I really hope you don't mind. I still thank you very much for the help though. Take care! :)